# Mime format message

Tags: gmail, utf-8, mime-types, base64, email-bounces

How to read mime encoded files? We have converted .msg file to .mhtml for better reading without MS Outlook. But we cannot read encoded text in bounced mails. message is as

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Message-ID: <9C7556267CD1450D9A218C33DE90623C.MAI@home>
RGVhciBjdXN0b21lciw8YnI+PGJyPiZuYnNwOyZuYnNwOyZuYnNwOyZuYnNwO1RoZSBwYXNzd29yZCBvZiB5b3VyIGFjY291bnQgaW4gV2lubWFu4oCZcyB3ZWJzaXRlIGlzICIqKioqKioqKioiLjxicj48YnI+VGhhbmtpbmcgeW91LDxicj48YnI+V2lubWFuIFNvZnR3YXJlIFB2dC4gTHRkLg==
```

how to read this? Any programme to read this? Or any exe is available for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an online [base64 converter](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) to decode this type of email.

```
Dear customer,<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The password of your account in Winman’s website is "*********".<br><br>Thanking you,<br><br>Winman Software Pvt. Ltd.
```

Comment: Yes, we already tried with online Base-64 decoder. But we want to implement in our programme. So we have to create exe for that. Any free exe is available? Or any open programme?

Comment: We got one exe from sourceforge.net. But in that we have to input the base64 part of message. It will not load whole file. Is we load entire items in file, it saying that "Data contains no legal base64 code!". What we have to do? How we can decode all items in it?

Comment: The best applications for reading emails formatted with MIME encoding are email applications.  Perhaps a better approach would be to go back a step and describe why you are doing what you are doing so those here can provide alternative approaches.

Comment: Thank you. http://www.fpx.de/fp/Software/UUDeview/  solved our problem.